# Get all Magento Categories using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.8

I have this SQL query to get all Magento Categories.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cc.entity_id AS id,
    cc.`value` AS path,
    cc1.`value` AS `NAME`,
    cce.`level`,
    cce.parent_id
FROM
    catalog_category_entity_varchar cc
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id = cc1.entity_id
JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON cc.entity_type_id = ee.entity_type_id
JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id = cce.entity_id
WHERE
    cc.attribute_id = '57'
AND cc1.attribute_id = '41'
AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category'
```

This returns all categories except the one I created a new category from Magento backend but that is not showing.

That category is published and has no products in it. 
Following image is from `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table.

[image]

`entity_id = 449` is showing when I run that query, because it has `attribute_id = 57 and 41`

But I am talking about `entity_id = 452` that is not showing, because it does not have `attribute_id = 57`.

I want to ask Magento experts, what does `attribute_id = 57` belong to? and how can I fix this query to fetch all categories?
**PS**
I want Pure SQL query, No Magento code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting categories from EAV category model which has attributes `57` and `41` of `varchar` type :

```
cc.attribute_id = '57'
cc1.attribute_id = '41'
```

According to my 1.9 magento installation this are `name` and `path` attributes of `catalog/catagory`:

`select distinct ea.attribute_code from eav_attribute as ea inner join catalog_category_entity_varchar as vc  on ea.attribute_id=vc.attribute_id where vc.attribute_id in (57,41);`

To get all raw categories use this sql:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3')'
```

or to get categories with names use this:

```
SELECT `e`.*,
       IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`
FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '41')
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '41')
```

Comment: from which table? I can post it if you tell me table

Comment: also please remove our discussion comments here ... so future readers wont read our comments and dont waste their time :P

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess...

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.entity_id id
              , cc.value path
              , cc1.value NAME
              , cce.level
              , cce.parent_id
           FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar cc
           LEFT
           JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 
             ON cc.entity_id = cc1.entity_id
            AND cc1.attribute_id = 41
           JOIN eav_entity_type ee 
             ON cc.entity_type_id = ee.entity_type_id
           JOIN catalog_category_entity cce 
             ON cc.entity_id = cce.entity_id
          WHERE cc.attribute_id = 57
            AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category'
```

Comment: It also returned same number of results :( didnt return that category that I am missing

Comment: @AndhiIrawan unless you're going for the archaeologist badge, I'm not sure that there's much merit in commenting on posts from 5 years ago.